# POST http://localhost:53178/api/LocationSearchApi 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, http

This one is my service:

```
    latModule.service('latLocationSvc',
        ["$http", "$resource",
          function ($http, $resource) {
     this.post = function (params) {
                     var request = $http({
                          method: "post",
                          url: "/api/LocationSearchApi",
                          data: params
                      });
                      return request;
                  };
    }]);
```

This one is my controller :

```
     $scope.searchFilterData = function() {
            var params = {
                SponsorIcaCid: 88150,
                OwnerIcaCid: null,
                Cid: null,
                TerminalId: null,
                RtnCode: null,
                LocationName: null,
                LocationTypeCode: null,
                OwnerName: null,
                CountryCode: null,
                Address: null,
                City: null,
                StateProv: null,
                Postal: null,
                FromLastUpdateDate: null,
                ToLastUpdateDate: null,
                ErrorCode: null,
                ViewFilterType: 5,
                IsExportRequest: null,
                ExportLocations: null,
                MerchantName: null,
                MerchantCategory: null,
                MccCode: null,
                DataProviderType: null,
                DataProviderId: null,
                PhoneNumber: null,
                OptedOut: null

            };
            var promisePost = latLocationSvc.post(params);
            promisePost.then(function(response) {
                $scope.locationDtlsList = response;
            },function (){});

        };
```

While calling this post api I am getting the following error.

```
POST http://localhost:53178/api/LocationSearchApi 404 (Not Found)
```

What I need to do to overcome this error? When I call an API by implementing service with $resource it works but before the call completes it triggers the events after that data comes. Due to this reason I am unable to bind data to my view. So I am trying to implement this.

Comment: you can use $timeout [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for check and call event after data comes, I list two different ways for handle it.

**1)** Using [$viewContentLoaded](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3AngView)

`$viewContentLoaded` event is emitted that means to receive this event you need a parent controller like

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

From MainCtrl you can listen the event

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
        $timeout(function() {
            //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
        },0);
    });
});
```

Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded. According to documentation of `$viewContentLoaded`, it supposed to work

**2)** Using [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

**JS:**

```
.directive( 'elemReady', function( $parse ) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ) {    
          elem.ready(function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                var func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
                func($scope);
            })
          })
       }
    }
});

$scope.callMethod = function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div elem-ready="callMethod()"></div>
```

I would argue this is the recommended Angular way because the main benefit of this is that you can be as broad or granular your UI as you like and you are working with DOM logic from your controllers.

Let me know if any concern/query for this.

Comment: Actually while I am trying to implement this through a service using $resource  var obj = $resource(baseUrl,
             {
                 filter: params,
                 userId: userId,
                 serviceTypeCode: serviceTypeCode
             },
              {
                  post: {
                      method: 'POST',
                      params: {},
                      isArray: false
                  }
              });
              obj.post({}, function (response) {
                  vm.locationDtls = response;
                  callback(response);

Comment: and in controller latLocationSvc.getLocationList(function (result) {
        $scope.locationDtlsList = result; }); The rest call get completes ,but when I try to use ng-repeat on the retrived object it's not wotking ,because before the controller gets the response the ng-repeat get executed.

Comment: I think you need to use `$timeout` for `$scope.locationDtlsList = response;` Have you tried this?